# Should you ever use BOTH of the OPTIONS "Recompile" and "Optimize For" on a Single Query?

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited about 20 stored procedures that have every query ending in:

```
OPTION(RECOMPILE, OPTIMIZE FOR(@big_id = 999))
```

To my understanding of these options, it is telling the server to recompile this statement's execution plan every time, and telling it to use that single number to do its optimization every time as well.

So isn't it simply recompiling the EXACT SAME PLAN every time because of the "Optimize For" option?

Or am I missing some "secret sauce" in the Constant Folding that is doing something magic?

(To me it looks like it is wasting cycles with constant query recompiles)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct about it recompiling every time and recompiling executing plan for the same number. My first guess would be, it is the result of a developer working with a very small set of data in UAT where number 999 for some sort of test data and it did make the difference there. I would start by  commenting these lines out and monitor the performance. Again nothing can be said for sure maybe it actually works. But since you have mentioned that it is in every proc, I am pretty sure it is there just because someone thought it would help, but whether it actually.....

Comment: but whether it actually helps or not, you will have to find this out for yourself, like I said start commenting these lines out and lets see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other things such as statistics could have changed since the plan was generated, regardless of which value it was optimized for.

Saying that - its unlikely its actually worth recompiling each time. Sounds like someone managed to speed a query up once with that by coincidence and has applied it blindly to all the rest

Comment: I think you are on to something: The table in question is part of a huge bulk/ETL process. The record counts can make huge swings due to CRUD. So the stats are probably changing a lot. That means it might be best to at least check for a recompile for each query, and the `OPTIMIZE FOR` id is definitely the biggest row count for each query.

So it might actually be doing something ... the average run time is 5-10 seconds, so a few milliseconds to recompile is probably worth it.